# Placing points at the begin and the end of a polyline with google maps

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript

I try to apply polyline in google maps in angular4 with AgmCoreModule. I successfully applied polyline, but how to add point at the start and the end of the polyline ?

code html:

```
<div class="container">
      <agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
         <ng-container>
           <agm-polyline  [strokeColor]="color" [strokeWeight]="weight">
              <agm-polyline-point *ngFor="let test of lines" [latitude]="test.latitude" 
              [longitude]="test.longitude" >
              </agm-polyline-point>
          </agm-polyline>
        </ng-container>
      </agm-map>
    </div>
```

and typscript code is only array lines and color

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a specific structure solving your problem but is [AgmCircle](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/AgmCircle.html) a good solution for you ?

```
<div class="container">
    <agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
        <ng-container>
            <agm-circle [latitude]="lines[0].latitude" [longitude]="lines[0].longitude" 
                [fillOpacity]="0.5" [radius]="1000" ></agm-circle>
            <agm-circle [latitude]="lines[lines.length - 1].latitude" [longitude]="lines[lines.length - 1].longitude" 
                [fillOpacity]="0.5" [radius]="1000" ></agm-circle>
            <agm-polyline [strokeColor]="color" [strokeWeight]="weight">
                <agm-polyline-point *ngFor="let test of lines" [latitude]="test.latitude" [longitude]="test.longitude" ></agm-polyline-point>
            </agm-polyline>
        </ng-container>
    </agm-map>
</div>
```